# JList prints duplicate values on console, display single values on GUI

Tags: java, swing, jlist

I was trying to troubleshoot the code that why `JList` prints same values x2 times on console, but on GUI it shows only x1 time. I need ID on backend to do more functions, but it comes x2 time. The values are retrieving from DB.
JList Initialization & calling: -

```
CustomListModel listModel;
listModel = new CustomListModel(getListOfRoutes());
routeList = new JList<tbl_bom_route>(listModel);
ListSelectionListener myListener = new listListeners();
routeList.addListSelectionListener(myListener);
routeList.setCellRenderer(new routeListCellRenderer());
scrollPaneList.setViewportView(routeList);

class CustomListModel extends AbstractListModel<tbl_bom_route> {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        private ArrayList<tbl_bom_route> items;
        public CustomListModel(ArrayList<tbl_bom_route> items) {
            this.items = items;
        }
        @Override
        public int getSize() {
            return items.size();
        }

        @Override
        public tbl_bom_route getElementAt(int index) {
            return items.get(index);
        }
    }

 private ArrayList<tbl_bom_route> getListOfRoutes() {
            ArrayList<tbl_bom_route> itemsList = new ArrayList<>();
            try {
                itemsList = daoBomRouteObject.getAllListOfRoutes();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return itemsList;
        }

class routeListCellRenderer extends DefaultListCellRenderer {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        @Override
        public Component getListCellRendererComponent(JList<?> list, Object value, int index, boolean isSelected,
                boolean cellHasFocus) {
            super.getListCellRendererComponent(list, value, index, isSelected, cellHasFocus);
            if (value instanceof tbl_bom_route) {
                tbl_bom_route item = (tbl_bom_route) value;
                setText(item.getRouteName());
            }
            return this;
        }
    }
```

Console Output: -

- Route00476R1020ARDWN_No 4 Draw Bench
- ID186
- Route00476R1020ARDWN_No 4 Draw Bench
- ID186

Updated: -

```
private class RouteListListener implements ListSelectionListener {
        @Override
        public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e) {
            if (!e.getValueIsAdjusting()) {
                int selectedIndex = routeList.getSelectedIndex();
                if (selectedIndex != -1) {
                    tbl_bom_route selectedListValue = routeList.getSelectedValue();
                    SANDBOX_GROUP_ID = selectedListValue.getRouteGroupID();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You need to post the source of *listListeners* btw [class names start upper case and should not be plurals unless encapsulating a Collection](https://technojeeves.com/index.php/aliasjava1/106-java-style-conventions) I suspect you're not ignoring, when true, `event.getValueIsAdjusting()`

Comment: Class names SHOUILD start with an upper case character and NOT contain "_" characters. Learn and follow Java conventions. This is easy when you look at the class names in the API,

Comment: @g00se:- Unfortunately, I was missing the method `e.getValueIsAdjusting()`. It works fine now! Thank you for pointing out java notations